# How to delete more than one tag?

Tags: git, tags

I have a bunch of tags in my Git repository. Is it somehow possible to not delete every single tag but all tags which starts with some typical pattern?

I'd like to delete all tags which start with `v1.xxx` but not those which start with `v2.xxx`.

I *don't* want to delete all tags with:

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
```

I'd rather want to do something like:

```
git tag --delete v1.*
git push --delete origin v1.*
```

Any suggestions?

> UPDATE - How can I push more than one tag on remote?

Comment: If your shell supports it, you can use the completion functionality: Type `git tag --delete v1.` and then expand all completions (in Bash this is done with `Alt`+`*` by default, IIRC).

Comment: Refer to [the post to delete git tags by pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53735395/419348).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via Linux command you can delete multiple GIT Tags by separating with PIPE (|)

```
git tag | xargs git tag -d
```

Or you can delete all tags in the local repository:

```
git tag -d `git tag | grep -E '.'`
```

And, you can delete all tags that ends with _test

```
git tag -d `git tag | grep -E '^*\._test$'`
```

Yet another way:

```
git tag | ag *_test | xargs git tag -d
```

(using [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher))

Comment: so I rewrote your last command: $ git tag -d `git tag | grep -E 'v1.^*'` and this is deleting all tags which starts with v1.

BUT how can I push it on remote?

Comment: @Jules: you need to do 
git add -A
git commit -m "commit-message"
git push

to push these changes on remote.

Comment: You can't push a deleted tag with a normal git push. You have to do something like this:
git push origin :refs/tags/12345
OR
git push --delete origin tagName
OR
git tag -d tagName
but for my understanding this is only working with single tag-names

Comment: @Jules is mostly correct, but you can `git push --delete origin tag1 tag2 tag3 ... tagN`.  Note, however, that deleting your copy and their copy has no effect on *my* copy of those tags, and if I `git push --tags` to push *my* tags back to the server, they will all reappear! You must get *everyone who has them* to delete them.

Comment: ok thanks @torek - thats pretty painful but I will do it this way