# Delete multiple git remote tags and push once

Tags: git, tags

In Git, how can I delete multiple tags before pushing?

I know how to do it with one tag at a time. Not sure if it's possible to do multiple.

Comment: `git tag -d tag1 tag2 tag3 ...`

Comment: Can I do `git push` multiple too?

Comment: `git push origin :tag1 :tag2 :tag3 ...`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To delete locally multiple tags: [git tag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag):

> git tag -d <tagname>...

So simply:

```
git tag -d TAG1 TAG2 TAG3
```

To delete multiple tags remotely: [git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> git push [-d | --delete] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]

So simply:

```
git push ${REMOTE_NAME:-origin} --delete TAG1 TAG2 TAG3
```

**TL;DR:**

```
git tag -d TAG1 TAG2 TAG3
git push origin -d TAG1 TAG2 TAG3
```

Comment: Nice! For many people, it would be `git push origin --delete TAG1 TAG2 TAG3 `

Comment: You may also rewrite this as `git push origin -d TAG1 TAG2 TAG3 `

Comment: just to add 2p for posterity, it's two commands, not one: first `git tag -d ...` then `git push origin --delete ...`

Answer (score 100):

It will delete all matching tag patterns.

```
//Delete remote:
git push -d origin $(git tag -l "tag_prefix*")

// Delete local:
git tag -d $(git tag -l "tag_prefix*")

// Examples:
git tag -d $(git tag -l "v1.0*")
git push -d origin $(git tag -l "*v3.[2]*-beta*")
```

Comment: Works very good. Keep in mind that if you plan to delete locally AND remote, it makes sense to delete on the remote first because git would not find the tags locally otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way to delete all the tags that DON'T match the `tag_prefix`?

Comment: @MattiaAstorino [Ali Karaca's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69530274/419348) show a way to EXCLUDE `tags` by `grep -v`.

Comment: If you deleted the local tags first like me, this is how you can enumerate the tags from remote:

`git push -d origin $(git ls-remote --tags origin -l "tag_prefix*" | awk '{print $2}')`

Answer (score 46):

if you have too many tags (like in our case) you might want to do it like:

```
git tag -l > tags_to_remove.txt
```

then edit the file in your preferred editor - to review and remove the tags you want to keep (if any)
and then run it locally

```
git tag -d $(cat ./tags_to_remove.txt)
```

and remotely:

```
git push -d origin $(cat ./tags_to_remove.txt)
```

Comment: I like the pattern-matching answers too, but for my use this was the best answer. I don't clean out tags too often, so I didn't mind a step of manually verifying the list this way.

Comment: This is by far my favorite one! So simple and so clear about what you have to do. I will probably do this only a handful of times in my entire life, so learning something more complex makes little sense. Thank you so much for sharing this solution!

Comment: On Windows, easiest way after creating the file: 
`ForEach ($line in Get-Content tags_to_remove.txt) {git tag -d $line}`

Answer (score 19):

I found an easy way to do this if you have `grep` and `xargs` installed.  I am shamelessly taking this from https://gist.github.com/shsteimer/7257245.

Delete all the remote tags with the pattern your looking for:

```
git tag | grep <pattern> | xargs -n 1 -I% git push origin :refs/tags/%
```

Delete all your local tags:

```
git tag | xargs -n 1 -I% git tag -d %
```

Fetch the remote tags which still remain:

```
git fetch
```

Comment: To quote the comment on that gist; the `-i%` argument for `xargs` throws an illegal option error: replacing that with a capital such as `-I%` allows this to work.

Comment: I added `--color=never` to the grep command

Answer (score 6):

You can delete multiple tags with one command by specifying all the tags you want to delete

```
git tag -d 1.1 1.2 1.3
```

Then you can push all the deleted tags. Of course you can delete the tags with separate commands before pushing.

To push delete tags, just list all the tags you want to delete. The command is the same to delete one tag

```
git push --delete origin 1.1 1.2 1.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete everything **except**:

```
//Delete local
git tag -d $(git tag -l | grep -v "^YourTagNameToExcludeHERE*")

//Delete remote
git push -d origin $(git tag -l | grep -v "^YourTagNameToExcludeHERE*")
```

Extended @AechoLiu's great answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and want to get the best out from your automation and time, you could make it easier by listing all the remote tags into a file `sh` type.
with this command `git ls-remote --tags <git remote repo>` .

Than, in that file, replace the commit hash with the `git tag delete` command.

like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh
git push origin --delete    refs/tags/0.1.0
git push origin --delete    refs/tags/0.1.0^{}
git push origin --delete    refs/tags/0.1.1
git push origin --delete    refs/tags/0.1.10
git push origin --delete    refs/tags/0.1.100
git push origin --delete    refs/tags/0.1.101
git push origin --delete    refs/tags/0.1.102
git push origin --delete    refs/tags/0.1.103
git push origin --delete    refs/tags/0.1.104
```

once finished, change the file into an executable `chmod +x <file-name.sh`
than run the file like this:

```
./file-name.sh
```

the output should look like this:

```
- [deleted] refs/tags/0.1.104
```

and this will run recursively until finished.